# UITableView - "Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewCell' to AppName.CustomCell"

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am getting this error in my console when I try to open my table view:

> "Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewCell' to 
>       'AppName.NameTableViewCell'."

A couple points worth noting:

1. I am not using a storyboard
2. I have already registered my cell to the tableView in my viewDidLoad()

Here are some screenshots to clarify.

```
let tableView = UITableView()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    tableView.register(NameTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellName")
    ...
}

...

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cellName") as! NameTableViewCell
        cell.textCell.text = self.menuText[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do not post pictures of code. [Edit] your question and replace the pictures with your actual code, as text.

Comment: see , your main problem is in casting , it doesn't matter using one or more cells , that you should dequeue the cell not cast a regular tableview cell to your custom cell

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to change your code so that the cell class you're registering is actually being used in your `cellForRow` method. Try this:

```
func viewDidLoad() {
    tableView.register(NameTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellName")
    tableView.register(OtherTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "otherName")
    tableView.register(ThirdTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "thirdName")
}

func tableView(_ tableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexPath.row == 0 {
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellName", for: indexPath) as! NameTableViewCell
      // your cell setup code here
      return cell
    } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "otherName", for: indexPath) as! OtherTableViewCell
      return cell
    } else if indexPath.row == 2 {
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "thirdName", for: indexPath) as! ThirdTableViewCell
      return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention in my original post. The reason I am breaking my cellForRowAt: function into different if statements is because I am trying to add different data types for different rows.
So my first row will have a textField
And then the rest of the table (in the else statement) is supposed to be buttons . So I don't think I can use one cell object for the entire tableView like you're suggesting. Since different cells will be of different object types *i think*
^hoping i explained that clearly

Comment: The point is that you should use `tableView.dequeueReusableCell(...)` to create the cell, not explicitly create a `UITableViewCell` like you are now.

Comment: @dan you're right , it doesn't matter registering even 4000 cells , he would dequeue with right identifier

Comment: @benjamin852 I've expanded my answer to show how you could deal with multiple different cell classes. Simply register them all under different reuse identifiers and in `cellForRow` select the correct one. The main point is that you have to use the two-argument version of `dequeueReusableCell` for this to work.

Comment: @Gereon got it. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

You' re trying to cast a `UITableViewCell` to  `NameTableViewCell`

```
func tableView(_ tableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if(indexPath.row == 0)
    {
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"cellName1") as! NameTableViewCell1
      return cell
    }
   else
     if(indexPath.row == 1)
     {
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"cellName2") as! NameTableViewCell2
       return cell
     }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by checking the cell class in target section. it was missed.